# Calling a JQuery UI Dialog function from PHP

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I am quite new to the JQuery language but I have found a tutorial on the net that helped me to get the dialog working from a click button.

the function i use is as following:

```
$("#registration_ok").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").attr('title', 'Registration').text('Your Registration was Successfull!').dialog({ buttons: { 'Ok': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }}, open: function(){
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }, closeOnEscape: true, draggable: false, resizable: false, hide: 'fade', show: 'fade', modal: true, dialogClass: 'success'});
});
```

I now want to use this function and call it from a php file, but i cant get it to work.
I might need to rewrite the function since i think it will only respond on an actual click so i tried the following:

```
function dialog() {
    $("#dialog").attr('title', 'Registration').text('Your Registration was Successfull!').dialog({ buttons: { 'Ok': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }}, open: function(){
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }, closeOnEscape: true, draggable: false, resizable: false, hide: 'fade', show: 'fade', modal: true, dialogClass: 'success'});
};
```

I have tried to call the function in different ways, but none did work:

```
if(isset($_GET['success'])) { echo '<script type="text/javascript"> function() { dialog(); } </script>'; }
```

Or

```
if(isset($_GET['success'])) { echo '<script type="text/javascript"> dialog();</script>'; }
```

none did work, can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the code to be fired in a `.ready();` function?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

This will ensure the jquery only fires when the page has loaded. I suspect it's firing too early before all of the elements are present thus not working correctly.

The new code would look something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['success'])){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function(){
                  dialog();
              });
          </script>';  

}
?>
```

Comment: Thx :) that was the issue indeed. the code did fire too soon :)

Comment: Glad I could help! If you could mark the question as answered so it doesn't pop up in the unanswered tab anymore that would be great.